# UI flickers when using AdaptiveTrigger with Windows 10 UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm using adaptive triggers to provide two different UI depending on when my app is displayed in portrait or landscape mode:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.VerticalAlignment"
                 Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="Logo.Margin" Value="5,11,5,0"/>
                <Setter Target="Logo.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="550" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I've removed quite a few of my setters for simplicity sake, but whenever my page opens for the first time, I can see my UI flicker for a few milliseconds, but long enough for me to see it flicker from landscape mode to portrait mode when my phone is kept vertically i.e. portrait mode.

Is there a way to ensure that the correct adaptive trigger is set? Is there a way to check what the default trigger is when the page loads?

Thanks

**UPDATE - 1:**

Sorry I should have mentioned that these adaptive triggers are contained within a `UserControl` which is used as a DataTemplate in a `Listview`.

**UPDATE - 2:**

I've tried what @Quincy suggested and it definitely is an improvement at start up but it's definitely not behaving as well when resizing the Windows App Store, so my code now looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="NowNextGrid" Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed">   
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LogoPanel.VerticalAlignment"
                     Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Target="LogoPanel.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Target="LogoPanel.MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="Logo.Margin" Value="5,11,5,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="Logo.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Target="NowNextGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="550" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="NowNextGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I've added a name to my grid i.e. NowNextGrid and I'm setting the default `Visibility` to `Collapsed` by default and it is setting it to `Visible` in the VisualState.Setters for both the narrowView and wideView.

Hopefully, I understood correctly what @Quincy suggested. I'll keep looking if there is a better way but for now, I will leave it as while there seems to be a slight delay rebuilding my `Listview`, it is better than the flickering.

Comment: Maybe you have sets `x:Phase` in your DataTemplate ?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem by my side, maybe you can post the xaml code of your usercontrol.

Comment: @AskTooMuch, there is no x:Phase.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks for taking the time to try it out. I could, but there's really nothing special about it. There is no code behind as all the code is in my ViewModel and the UserControl just contains a grid which get modified dynamically (row gets hidden/visible) and controls that get displayed or hidden based on the size and a few converters are called but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your issue? I'm having the same and can't figure out how to avoid it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't yet.

Comment: @JérômeS. I don't know if you've resolve it, but I've just updated my question with more info that might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to `CurrentStateChanged` event in `VisualStateGroup` to check active state.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup CurrentStateChanged="CurrentStateChanged">
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.VerticalAlignment"
                 Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Target="LogoPanel.MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="Logo.Margin" Value="5,11,5,0"/>
                <Setter Target="Logo.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="550" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Code :

```
            private void CurrentStateChanged(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var activeState = e.NewState.Name;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Strangely, this does not get triggered when the page is initialized for the first time and the data is loaded and I can see this flicker. The second I resize my app on a windows 10 machine, and it gets over the set limit for the width, this gets triggered. If anything, I learned something new today. I wasn't aware of this event.

Comment: Yeah initializing doesn't "change" the state.  That event fires when states flip

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that the layout engine will display is your controls xaml without the visual state.  Then another layout cycle happens to apply the visual state.  That's what I'm guessing.

I think a solution could be putting opacity 0 on your control and making another setter for both visual states to make it opacity 1.

Comment: I've just updated my question based on what you suggested. Do you mind having a quick look and see if this is what you meant and also see my outcome. Better but still not 100% right.

Comment: Close!  Try to set opacity instead of visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this flickering seem not to be the AdaptiveTriggers themselves. The correct trigger was usually loaded in my tests. The flickering occurs when you use the new VisualState.Setters.

If you switch from them to the "old" way (Storyboard with ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames and KeyTime="0")  there is no flickering anymore.

So instead of:

```
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="200"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LogoPanel.(FrameworkElement.Width)" Value="100"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
```

try

```
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="200"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="LogoPanel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>100</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </VisualState>
```